# Facebook app - Javascript SDK, Getting the user id or e-mail of the page owner in which page tab app is added

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-fql, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm working on Facebook app, javascript sdk, C# SDK,

Developed a Facebook app as page tab.

The user can add the tab to their page. Once the tab is added to the page.

The user who adds the tab to their page ie., the page owner becomes admin. Whoever adds the tab app to their page becomes admin.

How to get the user id or e-mail of the page owner in which page tab app is added?

I tried out several thing couldn't able to find a solution.